# How to reference a field in the join model of a has_many though Rails 5 relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an app where users have many quizzes and quizzes can have many users. I have set the relationships:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :studies
        has_many :quizzes, through: :studies
    end
    class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :studies
        has_many :users, through: :studies
    end
    class Study < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :quiz
     end
```

I have a field in the Study table to store the score that the user made on the quiz, but I am unable to access the field. I have tried @quiz.studies.score and @quiz.study.score but Rails give me an undefined method. How to I access the field in a join model of a has_many though relationship?

Answer (score 1):

@quiz.studies return the collection of studies. So you have to use `first, last, each` to get the score of the specific studies.

Try this:

```
@quiz.studies.first.score
```